# Is there a fast way of going from a symbol to a function call in Julia?

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

I know that you can call functions using their name as follows

```
f = x -> println(x)
y = :f
eval(:($y("hi")))
```

but this is slow since it is using `eval` is it possible to do this in a different way? I know it's easy to go the other direction by just doing `symbol(f)`.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to accomplish? Needing to eval a symbol sounds like a solution in search of a problem. In particular, you can just pass around the original function, thereby avoiding issues with needing to track the scope of `f` (or, since `f` is just an ordinary variable in your example, the possibility that it would get reassigned), and with fewer characters to type:

```
f = x -> println(x)
g = f
g("hi")
```

> I know it's easy to go the other direction by just doing `symbol(f)`.

This is misleading, since it's not actually going to give you back `f` (that transform would be non-unique). But it instead gives you the string representation for the function (which might happen to be `f`, sometimes). It is simply equivalent to calling `Symbol(string(f))`, since the combination is common enough to be useful for other purposes.

Comment: Note also that f = x -> println(x)  can and should be simplified to  f = println.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I have found use for the above scenario. I am working on a simple form compiler allowing for the convenient definition of variational problems as encountered in e.g. finite element analysis.

I am relying on the Julia parser to do an initial analysis of the syntax. The equations entered are valid Julia syntax, but will trigger errors on execution because some of the symbols or methods are not available at the point of the problem definition.

So what I do is roughly this:

I have a type that can hold my problem description:

```
type Cmd f; a; b; end
```

I have defined a macro so that I have access to the problem description AST. I travers this expression and create a `Cmd` object from its elements (this is not completely unlike the strategy behind the `@mat` macro in `MATLAB.jl`):

```
macro m(xp)
  c = Cmd(xp.args[1], xp.args[3], xp.args[2])
  :($c)
end
```

At a later step, I run the `Cmd`. Evaluation of the symbols happens only at this stage (yes, I need to be careful of the evaluation context):

```
function run(c::Cmd)
    xp = Expr(:call, c.f, c.a, c.b)
    eval(xp)
end
```

Usage example:

```
c = @m a^b
...
a, b = 2, 3
run(c)
```

which returns `9`. So in short, the question is relevant in at least some meta-programming scenarios. In my case I have to admit I couldn't care less about performance as all of this is mere preprocessing and syntactic sugar.